# Como criar uma coluna fixa (col-md) em bootstrap?

Tags: css, html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Gostaria de manter a coluna esquerda fixa, e a direita movel.
Existe uma **classe bootstrap** ou uma outra tecnica pra resolver isso ?

**Tentei da seguinte forma :**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="position: fixed;">
        <p>conteudo fixo</p>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
        <p>conteudo movel</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Resultado**

- A coluna esquerda desaparece.
- O conteúdo da coluna direita deforma-se.

Comment: Qual a versão do BS você está utilizando?

Comment: Não pode-se usar `position:fixed` nesse caso. Ele não obedece algum elemento parent com `position: relative`. Ele é relativo ao `body`. Agora, não entendi o que quer fazer.

Comment: @Zooboomafoo acredito que o que ele quer é isso http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/

Answer (score 2):

[Um dos exemplos](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/) na documentação do Bootstrap v4 detalha muito bem como fazer esse tipo de efeito, com uma barra fixa e a outra com scroll.

Crie a estrutura HTML dessa forma:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 main">
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>

      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adicione ao CSS o estilo abaixo para fixar o `sidebar`:

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

.main {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenho uma aplicação nesse formato Sidebar fixa a esquerda e conteúdo a direita, uso as seguinte classes:

**Sidebar** (fixo, uma `div class="page-sidebar"`):

```
  <div class="page-sidebar " id="main-menu">
      <div class="user-info-wrapper sm">
        <div class="profile-wrapper sm">
          <?php
            echo '<img width="69" height="69" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(stream_get_contents($result1['IMAGEM'])).'">';
          ?>
```

**Conteúdo:** (dinâmico, de acordo com o conteúdo dentro de uma `div class="content"`)

```
<div class="content" style="padding-top:20px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
```

Espero ter ajudado.